# What is the time complexity of these loops 1 and 2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was going through an article on analysis of time complexity of loops at a very popular website(link given below) and according to that article the time complexity of below loops 1st and 2nd are O(1) and O(n) respectively.
But i think the time complexity of both loop is same O(n)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {  
    // some O(1) expressions
}
```

My reasoning : `c*n=O(n)

> after going through answers below , My reasoning is wrong as there is no varying input n. the loop run is fixed- c times. hence irrespective of the input value n , the loop will run constant time. so O(1) complexity

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += c) {  
    // some O(1) expressions
}
```

My reasoning : `c*n=O(n)`

Am i missing something ?I would be grateful if someone can help and explain

This is the link of the article : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A loop or recursion that runs a constant number of times is also
>   considered as O(1).

Here: `C` is a constant value. So basically, you are performing constant number of operation irrespective of the value of `n`

```
   // Here c is a constant   
   for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {  
        // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

Also in Second Loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += c) {  
    // some O(1) expressions
}
```

Your reason `c*n = O(n)` is **not correct**. Here 
Increment by `C`. For `n` elements, loops occur `n/c` which is asymptotically `O(n/c) ~ O(n)`

Comment: this whole loop is like a constant you mean as it's not dependent on varying input value- loop is fixed? right

Comment: Thank you very much Sakib for both 2 cases.I understand clearly  now

Answer (score 2):

> for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) { // some O(1) expressions    }

Here `c` is a constant. So basically, you are performing constant number of operation irrespective of the value of `n`. That is why is it considered as constant complexity, `O(1)`.

> for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += c) { // some O(1) expressions }

You are looping with a input value `n`, which is essentially variable with the given input to the program or algorithm. Now the `c` is again a constant, which will remain same for all the different values of `n`. The complexity is considered as `O(n)`.

> for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // some O(1) expressions }

This is same as the above only, just that value of the `c` is `1`.

All the complexities are represented in **asymptotic notation** format. **Constant factors** are removed because they will be same irrespective of the value of `n`.

Comment: He changed the question, go through once again.

Comment: Ok, lets take a simple print statement -SOP("hello World")- inside both loop , now isn't how many times this prints is dependent on value of input : n ?overall , shouldn't the time complexity be constant time taken to print a single time multiply with the input ?

Comment: Please check the answer now.

Comment: `c` is just a constant value. In first case it is `c` and later `1`.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no `n` in the picture, i dunno why you think it `O(n)`. The `loop` is going from `1 to c`, so its `O(c)`, and as `c` is a constant, the complexity is `O(1)`.

2) The loop starts from `1` and goes till `n`, incrementing `c` at every step. Clearly the complexity is `O(n/c)`, which asymptotically is `O(n)`.

Comment: @Harish : so both loops has O(n) complexity ? right: as in both case the how many times the constant inside loop is printed(- consider this a constant expression in loop) is dependent on value of input :n

Comment: @Naruto_Uzumaki BTW, in the link, its given `c` only for the first loop.

Comment: you are right. I just noticed that in link , it's c not n in ist loop .

Comment: @Naruto_Uzumaki Thats why i changed by answer. Initially i posted that the `1st` loop is constant.

Comment: "it's c not n" that makes the first loop constant doesn't it? oO

Comment: @Bene the OP keeps changing the question.. go through his edits history, you'll know

Answer (score 0):

**O(1) :** The complexity of this loop is O(1) as it runs a constant amount of time c.

```
// Here c is a constant   
   for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {  
        // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

**O(n):** The complexity of the loop is O(n) if it is incremented or decremented by constant amount. For example, these loops have O(n) time complexity.

```
// Here c is a positive integer constant   
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += c) {  
        // some O(1) expressions
   }

   for (int i = n; i > 0; i -= c) {
        // some O(1) expressions
   }
```