# Time complexity apparently exponential

Tags: time-complexity

I got a question
What would be the time complexity of this function?

```
Function (int n) {
 for (i = 1 to n):
    print("hello")
}
```

apparently it's exponential because of binary numbers or something?? 
it should be O(n) right?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536065/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-these-loops-1-and-2) help at all?

Comment: Can you share your thoughts about this, such that others could see if and where you are going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly `O(n)`. The function prints `"hello"` `n` times. So the time-complexity is `O(n)` and it is **not exponential**. It is **linear**.

Answer (score 0):

Since for loop is running from 1 to n, therefore complexity will be O(n). It is linear.